# How do I send mail from a shared mailbox alias from Outlook, using Office 365?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

I have a setup with a normal user (`user@domain.com`) and a shared mailbox (`shared@domain.com`) which has an alias (`alias@domain.com`). The user can send fine from the `shared@domain.com`, but not from `alias@domain.com`. It gets the message (translated from Dutch, so the actual message might be different):

> You do not have permission to send on behalf of the user.

How can I give this user permission to send from this alias?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, I tested in my lab, I created a shared mailbox, detail information in below screenshot and you could check permissions:[image]
[image]
I can send from shareM@domain.com and then I type sham@domain.com in From filed, it will automatically show as shareM@domain.com and send mails without any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message and the question, you may need to add the user to the "Send on behalf" delegation group. You've mentioned that the user can send as the shared mailbox but the error message indicates that the user is trying to "send on behalf". These are two separate modes of delegation. Either that or ensure that the end user is sending as the alias rather than sending on behalf of the alias. Hope this makes sense.